# Create Merge field in email template

Tags: email-template, merge-field

I have a question related to email template.

I have two object :
1. Sales order (This contain shipment type filed with Means_of_Transport__r as API )
2. Means of transport (This contain code filed as Code__c)

Now i am using merge formula as below :

{!KNDY4__Sales_Order__c.KNDY4__Means_of_Transport__r.KNDY4__Code__c}

But when i am using Send test and verify Merge field it's not taking any value for corresponding record.

Is this something i am using wrong logic ?

Comment: What is the type of email template and what is the relationship between fields? Also there is a typo here `{!KNDY4__Sales_Order__r.KNDY4__Means_of_Transport__r.KNDY4__Code__c}`

Comment: It's a text email template and field are coming from manage package and i used {!KNDY4__Sales_Order__r.KNDY4__Means_of_Transport__r.KNDY4__Code__c} also but this is also not working.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, it is not supported in Text template to get parent field value. You can use VF email template there you can access Parent field.

You can also vote this idea here.

[Cross Object Merge Fields in Email Template](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Brk7AAC)

Comment: or use cross object formula fields on the child field